# How to reuse a big, expensive-to-load dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, performance

I've got a 1 GB dictionary that takes a while to load into memory. But once the loading process is complete, running lookups in that dictionary is pretty fast.

How do I best reuse that loaded dictionary from various Python scripts that may get spawned in response to network requests?

I'd be interested in either general-purpose solution that I can test locally on my laptop before deploying to my Django server or, if there's none, in a Django-specific one.